# Why does the last entry of numpy.cumsum not necessarily equal numpy.sum

Tags: python, numpy

According to the docs for `numpy.cumsum`, "`cumsum(b)[-1]` may not be equal to `sum(b)`"

It gives the following example:

```
>>> b = np.array([1, 2e-9, 3e-9] * 1000000)
>>> b.cumsum()[-1]
1000000.0050045159
>>> b.sum()                    
1000000.0050000029
```

Clearly this has something to do with floating point rounding, but what would `numpy.sum` be doing differently that would account for this?

Comment: floating point precision, `numpy.sum` might just sum over different partitions (due to parallelization) than `numpy.cumsum()`, i.e, sequential addition from left to right.

Comment: @QuangHoang I didn't think that python employed parallelism by default (GIL), though it would make sense that the routine is designed to do it.

Comment: why? `(a+b) + (c+d) != ((a + b) + c) + d`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Yeah, it must not be executing in input order. But what order is it using?

Comment: @Lucas the GIL wouldn't be relevant, most numpy methods are calling out to highly optimized C routines and BLAS libraries. That's why it is fast

Comment: numpy implements `sum()` using "partial pairwise summation" (the documentation's term, it doesn't explain what makes it "partial") but here's an explanation of [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation). In short, it's not adding in order like `cumsum()` does.